# std::list.erase(itor) have differences between Android and Win32

Tags: c++, list

If I'm using an `iterator` in a for loop and I use `erase` on a current iteration of iterator, I found some differences between `Android` and `WIN32`

```
std::list<StackData*>::iterator itor;
std::list<StackData*>::iterator firstDelItor = __mStack.begin();
for(itor = __mStack.begin(); itor != __mStack.end();)
{
    firstDelItor = itor;
    PRINT_LOG(LOG_TAG, "A itor[%p] firstDelItor[%p]", *itor, *firstDelItor);
    itor = __mStack.erase(itor);
    PRINT_LOG(LOG_TAG, "B itor[%p] firstDelItor[%p]", *itor, *firstDelItor);
    ...
}
```

Android : After `erase(itor)`, value of `firstDelItor` is unchanged.

```
23766-23766 D/TAG: A itor[0x9b979fe0] firstDelItor[0x9b979fe0]
23766-23766 D/TAG: B itor[0x9b8e9dbc] firstDelItor[0x9b979fe0]
```

And on WIN32: Value of `firstDelItor` is changed to `0xdddddddd`.

```
TAG : A itor[0C6172D8] firstDelItor[0C6172D8]
Fatal at PRINT_LOG(LOG_TAG, "B itor[%p] firstDelItor[%p]", *itor, *firstDelItor); (itor = 0xcdcdcdcd, firstDelItor = 0xdddddddd)
```

So, please explain the difference between `Android` and `WIN32` in this case.

Comment: So you saved the same iterator you just erased, then dereferenced the now-invalidated iterator you saved. Trying to attached definition to what you witness after the erase is pointless. You've invoked *undefined behavior*. I.e, there is no definition to  find, so stop looking. That said, win32 is filling the space formerly occupied by the erased object with a fill-pattern, not that it matters.

Comment: Of course, the first Undefined Behavior was naming your variable `__mStack`. Any name containing two adjacent underscores is reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

"References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated."
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase

Comment: And it's not specified at all _how_ they're invalidated. That's why Android and Win32 can differ.